# How to add/update/auto-fill foreign key column with values from pirmary key column?

Tags: ssis

Here what i am trying to do.
I have a foreign key column in DBO.EMP_BK.PG, PG being the foreign key column.
Which references the primary key column in DBO.SALGRADE.GRADE, where grade is the primary key.

I would like to know how to auto fill foreign key column with values from primary key column.

Low sal =< SAL =< high sal,
where Low and High sal are columns in primary key table
and Sal in a column in foreign key table.

Based on the result of the expression use the appropriate grade value.
Also is it possible to do this using SSIS? Hope this make some sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use sql task element with query:

```
UPDATE DBO.EMP_BK
SET PG = (SELECT TOP 1 t1.GRADE
          FROM DBO.SALGRADE t1
          WHERE t1.[Low sal] <= DBO.EMP_BK.SAL
          AND t1.[high sal] >= DBO.EMP_BK.SAL)
```

By the way your question is totaly unclear, if you want better answer you need to give simple data with tables structure...

Comment: this query gonna take just one random value which gonna fit in low and high Sal, so if there are couple values you need to say which value take, because can be taken just one value